# Configure Unity Lenses and what they search

Tags: lenses, search

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

I've read about a lense (`ppa:pydave/unity-lenses`) that you can replace with the original files and folders lense, so you can search all your files. Instead of the current which only search used/recently used files and programs. I couldn't get this to work with 12.10, got a bunch of errors when I tried adding the ppa.

I would like to set up a lens that can search all my files and folders (from all of my 3 hdd's), one that search through my videos (ability to specify which folders) and the same for music. So basically I would like to set up three specific lenses that each get a set of specified folders that they search through.

If this is not possible, is there atleast a way to configure the current Files and Folders lense to ignore certain folders? I don't like when my dash shows files that I don't want to be shown.

I should add that I'm completely new to Ubuntu and I apologize beforehand if this information could easily be found. But I wasn't able to find something like this.

Edit: I found out how I can use the Privacy application to ignore what I want, so that's sorted now. Sorry for not researching it more. But my question regarding the lenses still stand. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).